# Can I "properly" run a vimscript in the background?

Tags: bash, vim

I'd like to run a peice of vim script in the background (preferably on windows, although if it only works on *nix, that's ok too)

The idea would be the following:

- User calls vimscript function (probably via a shortcut key)
- Status bar updates to say that the process is running
- Background script (bash or windows batchfile) kicks off - I can continue working
- Sometime later (say a few seconds) - the script completes and the status bar updates.

if I just run the script with an ampersand, then the script executes in the background and statusbar immediately updates to complete. If I run the script without the Ampersand, then it blocks me doing anything else until it completes.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386040/asynchronize-vim-script) and [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/QF7Bzh1YABU/02-YGr7_sCwJ) suggest it's not possible, but I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: All signs point to no. From what I remember, Vim doesn't have any such feature (and the developer hasn't accepted any patches to add it). You might have better luck with Neovim.

Answer (score 2):

Running Vimscript asynchronously *in the same Vim instance* is indeed impossible, and there's a much higher likelihood that you'll see this feature in Neovim first.

That said, you can asynchronously execute *external commands*, and feed back information to the current Vim instance.

- A simple approach would be polling for an external file (which is filled by the external command with its results). This could be done via `autocmd CursorHold`, or from the evaluation of `'statusline'` (but not too often, to avoid dragging down editing).
- The external script could also "call back" into the original Vim instance via its *client-server* feature (cp. `:help new-vim-server`). You'd have to pass `v:servername` to the script and then call back via `vim --servername {name} --remove-expr`. Note: On Unix, this feature requires an X server, so you'd limit the applicability with this approach.
- The [vim-misc plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-misc/blob/master/doc/misc.txt#L171) implements the latter as Vimscript evaluation in a second Vim instance; this gets as close to asynchronous Vimscript evaluation as possible.

Comment: Thanks - that helps - I'll give it a try, and accept your answer if I can get it to work.